# Need to add one more criteria to Sumproduct + Sumif formula

Tags: excel, sumproduct

KS
Kala Sha JahanCreated on June 3, 2021
Need to add one more criteria to Sumproduct + Sumif formula
Good evening,

I am using the following formula on Tab01, Cell E5:

=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF('Rolling Average Usages'!$F:$F,K5:L5,'Rolling Average Usages'!$L:$L))

*this formula returns the sum of all matches from the list in K5:L5. The math returns 12373 (which is correct).

[Tab01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1lFuV.png)

I would like to add the variable to include the value in cell B5 so that it returns just the values that correspond to it. the Tab02 picture shows the values, and the desired result should be 619+350=969.

[Tab02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vr4yg.png)

Help to add one more criteria would be appreciated.  I can add each lookup criteria manually, but the formula starts to become quite large.  is there anyway to add the criteria for "Store" in the criteria and keep the formula smaller?

thank you.

Comment: Took a while, found answer @ https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/11/12/excel-sumifs-sumif-multiple-criteria/ in Example 3. SUMPRODUCT & SUMIFS